# Getting Blocked loading mixed active content error message

Tags: css, http, laravel-5, https

I'm getting following error even when I've added https in place of http and also tried writing slashes // but still it's the same. I've checked code in browser and it's using https protocol then why it's giving this error?

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300”
```

here is the link of my website: https://colorinmotion5k.com/

it's in Laravel and I've also added https in .env file for App Url.

Comment: Just change it to `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300`

Comment: It's not working. I did that as you can see in code by view source option in browser. @CalvT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `square-gallery.css` is requesting `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300`, which is via HTTP.

So if you go to your site, and go `frontend` > `css` and edit `frontend/css/square-gallery.css` and change

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300
```

to

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300
```

it should solve it.

Comment: I've read and tried all the solutions including this you mentioned for fixing this error but still nothing changed. You can visit at given URL and check yourself that it's https in code but still giving error